# Option selector value changing after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a dropdown that would attach the value to the URL when user selects an option from the drop-down. But when the page is refreshed, the default/1st option gets selected.

```js
var saveclass = null;

function saveTheme(cookieValue) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('ThemeSelect');

  saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
  document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + sel.value;

  setCookie('theme', cookieValue, 365);
}

function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
  var today = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();

  if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)
    nDays = 1;

  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
  console.log("the cookie value is:")
  console.log(cookieValue)
  window.location.pathname = `/${cookieValue}`
}
```

```html
<select id="ThemeSelect" onchange="saveTheme(this.value);">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Using localStorage would be simpler than using cookie. You need to read the stored value on page load and set class and the select value also

Comment: @charlietfl How can I do that? Have you got an example or can you do this on fiddle please?

Comment: You use `localStorage.setItem(keyName, value)` and `localStorage.getItem(keyName)` when page loads

Comment: @charlietfl Using that is also defaulting to the first option on page reload.

Comment: ` function setLocal(value){
      let selectedLanguage = document.getElementById('ThemeSelect').value;
      console.log("selectedLanguage is:"+ selectedLanguage)
      localStorage.setItem('language', selectedLanguage)
      let displayLanguage=localStorage.getItem('language');
      console.log(displayLanguage);
      window.location.pathname = `/${displayLanguage}`
    } `